# Chocolate fondant vs. liquid chocolate cake

Tags: cake, chocolate, fondant

What is the difference between chocolate fondant and liquid chocolate cake? They are quite similar and visually indistinguishable.

Comment: by "liquid chocolate cake", are you talking about a cake with a center that hasn't fully set?

Comment: @Joe: Yes, a melted chocolate center. And a chef in the TV show "master chef" asked the contestants this question and got no satisfying answer.

Comment: And it seems that there's a 'chocolate fondant' that's also a cake with a liquid center ... in the US it typically refers to a coating put over the cake (either rolled or poured), or can be used for modeling figures when it's stiff.